# Checking the value of close by elements in a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

consider the following matrix:

```
[[true,false,false,true], 
 [false,false,true,false], 
 [true,true,false,true]]
```

I want python to check the value of the elements close to each element.For instance the [0][0] element is true and the three elements surrounding it are false so it should return some thing like [0,0,0].

```
     (element),false
     false,false
```

for the [0][1] element the result should be [1,0,0,1,0]:

```
     true,(element),false
     false,false,true
```

and so on(the order of 0 and 1's don't really matter,just the number of them).I'v been trying to use some algorithms to do this but first it takes a lot of time since the element in the vicinity of each item varies and using (for,while) loops becomes very tricky and second the execution time would become very long. My question is that is there any library or method (something like numpy) to make my work easier ?

Comment: the `[0][1]`-element has `len([1,0,0,0,1,0]) = 6` surrounding elements? how so? please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you for noting that,I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
mat = [[True, False, False, True],
       [False, False, True, False],
       [True, True, False, True]]

max_i = len(mat)
max_j = len(mat[0])

def surrounding(i, j):

    ret = []

    for ii in range(max(0, i-1), min(i+2, max_i)):
        for jj in range(max(0, j-1), min(j+2, max_j)):
            if (ii, jj) == (i, j):
                continue
            ret.append(int(mat[ii][jj]))
    return ret
```

note the `min` and `max` functions inside the `range`s that take care of the borders of your matrix.

and as python `bool`s are subclasses of `int` anyway, `True` and `False` can just be cast to `int`.